# Как в listbox вписать несколько полей, при этом, чтобы отображалось одно, но при выборе получать значения остальных?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

Вот что я написал:

```
list1 = Listbox(
    master = main_frame,
    width = 45,
    height = 12
)

def lets_add_account(Event):
    items1 = {"name":add_account_entry_name.get(), "login":add_account_entry_login.get(), "password":add_account_entry_password.get()}
    list1.insert(END, items1[name])
```

При выборе нужно получить логин и пароль, а в listbox должно отображаться только имя. Как это сделать? Данные нужно получить именно из поля.

Comment: Не очень понятно зачем эти данные хранить в listbox? Храните в БД, например в XML.

Comment: Да, верно. Не знаю, что на меня нашло...